# Symfony2 FOSREST JMS\Serializer bundles error

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Can you help to fix the following error?

```
InvalidArgumentException: "fos_rest.serializer" must implement FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Serializer (instance of "JMS\Serializer\Serializer" given).
in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\src\FOS\RestBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\SerializerConfigurationPass.php line 58
at SerializerConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler.php line 117
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php line 613
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2502
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2281
at Kernel->boot() in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2312
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in C:\wamp\www\SymfonyRestAPI\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: This is too broad. But i think you must add the code of your config file. Which class is related to "fos_rest.serializer"

Comment: I followed all the steps of symfony tutorial but always the same error, in appKernel.php file i added             new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle()

Comment: in composer.json i added         "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.x-dev"   but same error again

Comment: Please add the content of your comments in the answer. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @A.L probably means: 'Please add the content of your comments in the *question*'

Comment: @GitaarLAB you're right, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

This exception has been introduced in FOSRestBundle 2.0 (see [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/8a1a4a55d9220e3de1b4af0a5b3137fb4ff27a65/DependencyInjection/Compiler/SerializerConfigurationPass.php#L57)) because of a serializer abstraction layer introduced in 2.0 too.
It is normally automatically managed by the bundle which detects the JMS serializer.

Did you add the JMSSerializerBundle to your kernel as following?

```
// app/AppKernel.php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),,
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

This should be the problem here.

If it isn't, then maybe you tried to define directly the serializer FOSRestBundle uses, **the following is a bad practice most of the time and should only be used if you know what you do**:

```
// services.yml
services:
    fos_rest.serializer:
        // This won't work in case your class doesn't
        // implement FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Serializer
        class: My\Serializer
```

If my second proposition is your case, you custom serializer has to implement the interface `FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Serializer`.

Comment: How do you do that? Can you please explain it in your answer?

Comment: Sorry I mean this could be what makes this error happen, I'll improve my answer.

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/commit/db66463430d048fbe38619df35490c2980c3e82c#diff-b4c2bb665099019e5209acdfe6371d2a